# OS X: How to programmatically find locked CoreStorageVolumes

Tags: disk, disk-io

I have programmatically find out the status of the CoreStorage volumes.

Using IOServiceXyz / IORegistryXyz / ... methods do not work for ***locked*** volumes - that means if a user did not (yet) enter the password I do not see informations about this volume.

Using **diskutil cs list** and/or **diskutil cs info** helps but I have to start diskutil and scan the output. I do not like this way because it is a little bit slow (start a program using exec, ...)

- Is there a better way?
- At least diskutil can do it - so what API uses diskutil?
- There is a libCoreStorage.dylib but I could not find any documentation about it. Where is it?

Any help is appreciated!
Regards